# Python asyncio how to detect unexpected exceptions

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm building a project on top of Django Channels and as such, I would like to avoid mucking with code above my sub-classed consumer.

With asyncio, uncaught and unexpected exceptions aren't being thrown to the console even with asyncio debug enabled, and Python dev mode enabled.

I came up with the following so that async code I develop can be wrapped in a task, and automatically capture exceptions, log them, and so on:

```
async def _task_monitoring(self):
    while True:
        for task in self._task_list:
            if task.done():
                self._task_list.remove(task)

                try:
                    _ = task.result()
                except ConnectionClosedError:
                    self.log.warning(traceback.format_exc())
                    self.user_warning(f'remote connection disconnected unexpectedly')

                    continue
                except ConnectionClosedOK:
                    self.user_warning(f'Remote connection shutdown')

                    continue
                except asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError:
                    self.log.warning(f'task {task.get_name()} was cancelled')
                    continue
                except Exception as e:
                    self.log.error(traceback.format_exc())
                    raise e
```

when I use `asyncio.create_task` I add the resulting task to `self._task_list`. I know this probably isn't the best use of resources, but it's what I have to work with right now.

My main question concerns the blanket `except Exception as e:` which is not good practice I know, but is the best way I can be sure to see the exception from a coroutine in instances where I don't otherwise expect one.

Is there a better way to handle unexpected exceptions in asyncio coroutines?

Comment: This seems okay to me overall. The "uncaught" exceptions are logged as they occur, which is better by far than simply suppressing them altogether. And re-raising them with `raise e` serves to notify the end user. If this is a console-only application, this is about as close to best-practice as you'll get barring catching every possible exception individually.

Comment: Exceptions from a coroutine or task are raised when you `await` it and you can handle them normally as in non-async code. Can you show an example where this does not work for you?

Comment: Note that your monitoring task cannot be cancelled since it mixes child and self cancellation.

Comment: Are you aware of TaskGroups? You generally shouldn’t need generic task watchers/monitors because the tasks to monitor should already be "monitored" by whatever code created them. Rolling out your own concurrency primitives is rarely needed until you build a custom, generic library for that (which of course you might be doing here).

Comment: @mkrieger1 so it DOES work, but my "current model" has some tasks that just run and complete at some time in the future and I typically don't care unless there was an exception. I don't want to await as I want the task to complete whenever it can without blocking the current async function. I'm open to the idea that my understanding of async function execution is severely lacking.

Comment: You might want to look into `asyncio.gather` as well.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi not sure what you mean...? it works the way I expect it to. My issue is that without something like the above, I would need to await the coroutine or the task, which I don't think I want to do. However, as I mentioned above as well, my core understanding may be garbage. In my head I was thinking "all async or nothing" but perhaps there needs to be a healthier mix of sync and async.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a wrapper around trying to get the task result, and them checking if that raises is basically the *one* way to catch and log exceptions in tasks.

As for your concern about having to keep track of all tasks in a list (a set can be used, and may have some, small advantages): there should be no concern-  to the contrary, one can't just call `asyncio.create_task` in Python and forget about the scheduled tasks: it will lead to hard do debug Heisenbugs:
As the asycio Loop itself does not keep any hard-references to tasks, tasks not annotated elsewhere can simply "disappear" and be forgotten. It is not obvious and a hard to reach condition, but it is barely warned about in the docs. In my tests, I get this when I schedule about 2K tests before yielding to the event loop.

Now, having to iterate over this container of active tasks checking their results, really is not needed. (But if you prefer to, you could call `asyncio.wait` to iterate over the "done" tasks only, not all of them).
What can be done in this case is to add a "done callback" to each of your tasks, which will try to retrieve the task result, and log an exception if any - https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.Task.add_done_callback

Despite the warning for "this should only be done for low level code" in the docs, that in my experience is cleaner than having to keep explicitily cycling through your set of active tasks elsewhere, as the asyncio loop already does that - and looks more like a phrase inserted by a purist at a certain point - if one will understand  "asyncio purism" as "no callbacks ever".

Anyway, at the point you create each task, schedule a callback by calling
`task.add_done_callback` to what is essentially the main body of your function above:

```
def xxxxx(self, ...):
   ... 
   task = asyncio.create_task(...)
   self._task_set.add(task)
   task.add_done_callback(self.check_exceptions)
   ...

def check_exceptions(self, task):
   
    self._task_set.remove(task)  # prefer a set than a list -  'remove' gets much better

    try:
        _ = task.result()
    except ConnectionClosedError:
        ...
    ...
```

Comment: indeed, I had used the add_done_callback elsewhere, but I felt odd given that warning. Guess it ultimately does come down to preference. I'm doing this all alone, so flip flopping strategies until I find the right one is ok...

Comment: What I do in a solo project is to have a "stand alone" inifinite task (running with a "while True") that awaits `asyncio.wait(_task_set)`  - and then check all that are marked as done, and updates ``_task_set` with the pending ones (the two complementar sets are returned by the `asyncio.wait` call) .

Comment: ah perfect, it wasn't clear how .wait would be used with done, but now it is obvious. Thanks!